# How can I Get only the value 9 from this input using xpath?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have some HTML as shown below

```
<ol Class="z1">
        <li><h3>Number Theory - HCF LCM</h3>
            <p lang="title">How many pairs of integers (x, y) exist such that the product of x, y and HCF (x, y) = 1080?</p>
            <ol class="xyz">
                <li>8</li>
                <li>7</li>
                <li>9</li>
                <li>12</li>
            </ol>
        <ul class="exp"><li class="grey fleft"><span class="qlabs_tooltip_bottom qlabs_tooltip_style_33" style="cursor:pointer;"><span><strong>Correct Answer</strong>Choice (C).</br>9</span> Correct answer</span></li><li class="primary fleft"><a href="hcf-lcm_1.shtml">Explanatory Answer</a></li><li class="grey1 fleft">HCF LCM</li><li class="red1 flrt">Hard</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
</ol>
```

I am interested in grabbing the value **9 under Correct Answer** from the ul whose class is exp that follows the br

I wrote an existing Xpath query that gets everything but doesnt quite do the job "'.//ul[@class="exp"]/li/span/span/text()'"

Any help is highly appreciated?

Trying to run this xpath expression on scrapy

```
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cat_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://iim-cat-questions-answers.2iim.com/quant/number-system/hcf-lcm/']

    def parse(self, response):
        CLASS_SELECTOR = '//ol[@class="z1"]/li'
        problems = []
        for lis in response.xpath(CLASS_SELECTOR):
            question = lis.xpath('.//p[@lang="title"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            choices = lis.xpath('.//ol[@class="xyz"]/li/text()').extract()
            ANSWER_SELECTOR = './/ul[@class="exp"]/li/span/span/text()[not(contains(.,"Choice"))]'
            correct_answer = lis.xpath(ANSWER_SELECTOR).extract_first()
            explanation = lis.xpath('.//ul[@class="exp"]/li[2]/a/@href').extract_first().strip()
            difficulty = lis.xpath('.//ul[@class="exp"]/li[last()]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            p = Problem(question,choices, correct_answer, explanation, difficulty)
            print(question, choices, correct_answer)
```

Comment: You want to get only `9`  text right ?  which is in correct answer

Comment: yes @NarendraRajput

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [below expression](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Col%20Class%3D%22z1%22%3E%0A%20%3Cli%3E%3Ch3%3ENumber%20Theory%20-%20HCF%20LCM%3C%2Fh3%3E%0A%20%3Cp%20lang%3D%22title%22%3EHow%20many%20pairs%20of%20integers%20(x%2C%20y)%20exist%20such%20that%20the%20product%20of%20x%2C%20y%20and%20HCF%20(x%2C%20y)%20%3D%201080%3F%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%3Col%20class%3D%22xyz%22%3E%0A%20%3Cli%3E8%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%3Cli%3E7%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%3Cli%3E9%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%3Cli%3E12%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fol%3E%0A%20%3Cul%20class%3D%22exp%22%3E%3Cli%20class%3D%22grey%20fleft%22%3E%3Cspan%20class%3D%22qlabs_tooltip_bottom%20qlabs_tooltip_style_33%22%20style%3D%22cursor%3Apointer%3B%22%3E%3Cspan%3E%3Cstrong%3ECorrect%20Answer%3C%2Fstrong%3EChoice%20(C).%3C%2Fbr%3E9%3C%2Fspan%3E%20Correct%20answer%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%3Cli%20class%3D%22primary%20fleft%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22hcf-lcm_1.shtml%22%3EExplanatory%20Answer%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%3Cli%20class%3D%22grey1%20fleft%22%3EHCF%20LCM%3C%2Fli%3E%3Cli%20class%3D%22red1%20flrt%22%3EHard%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%3C%2Fol%3E&=Correct%20answer&extract=%2F%2Ful[%40class%3D%22exp%22]%2F%2Fstrong[.%3D%22Correct%20answer%22]%2Ffollowing%3A%3Atext()[2]&=%2F%2Ful[%40class%3D%22exp%22]%2F%2Fstrong[.%3D%22Correct%20answer%22]%2Ffollowing%3A%3Atext()[2]&input-format=html&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2) and let me know if it's not what you need:

```
//ul[@class="exp"]//strong[.="Correct answer"]/following::text()[2]
```

Comment: this one returns null, from what i understand , are you trying to search the text correct answer inside strong

Comment: No. This should locate `"9"` below **"Correct answer"**.

Comment: nope returns [NULL] this is the actual page source where i tested the xpath expression http://iim-cat-questions-answers.2iim.com/quant/number-system/hcf-lcm/

Comment: `//ul[@class="exp"]//br/following::text()[1]` same result?

Answer (score 3):

Use following xpath to get your required text

```
.//ul[@class="exp"]/li/span/span/text()[not(contains(.,'Choice'))]
```

Comment: works on xpath chrome plugin but doesnt work inside scrapy, gives NONE everywhere

Answer (score 1):

```
response.xpath('//ol[@class="xyz"]/li[3]/text()').extract_first()
```

**UPDATE**

```
check = response.xpath('//ol[class="z1"]/li/ul/li/span/strong/text()').extract_first()
if "Correct answer" in check :
    correct_answer = response.xpath('//ol[class="z1"/li/ol/li[3]/text()').extract_first()
```

Comment: thanks for posting the solution, however the correct answer is not found in those 4 options, it is mentioned below inside the ul whose class = exp